# Contribute to Eclipse context menu when file and parent project meet conditions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to contribute a context menu only when the following 2 conditions are met:

1.- If selected file has .txt extension
2.- If parent project of the selected file has an specific facet

I can do this by separate using the following conditions using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point, i.e: for the project facet:

```
<with variable="activeMenuSelection">
    <iterate operator="and" ifEmpty="false">
        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
            <test property="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.projectFacet" value="jst.code.quality" forcePluginActivation="true" />
        </adapt>
    </iterate>
</with>
```

And for the file extension:

```
<with variable="activeMenuSelection">
    <iterate operator="and" ifEmpty="false">
        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
            <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension" value="txt" forcePluginActivation="true" />
        </adapt>
    </iterate>
</with>
```

But I have problems to combine this two conditions since the `activeMenuSelection` variable will only contain the file and I can't use it to test the project facet, is there a variable I can use to access the active project in the same condition?

Comment: Putting both `adapt` elements under the same `iterate` element does not work as desired?

Comment: No, because the `activeMenuSelection` variable is getting only the file I right clicked, not the parent project

Answer (score 1):

The `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.projectFacet` test will work on any `IResource` so it will work on an `IFile` as well as an `IProject`. So you can combine the tests.

Comment: It works, thanks. In the future I will have to create a couple of custom property testers, in which the classes will not be compatible with each other so I will not be able to combine them like this, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You may be able to use `<or>` operators, but that is really another question.